# Simple-framework XML deserializing ValueRequiredException

Tags: java, android, parsing, simple-framework, serialization

Can anyone tell me why my deserializer isn't working?

Main.java

```
    try {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream  inputStream = assetManager.open("data.xml");
        Data d = serializer.read(Data.class, inputStream);
        System.out.println("[JOE]: "+d.getPokemon().getName());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("[JOE] error:  "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

data.xml:

```
<Data>

    <Pkmn> 
        <nm>Beedrill</nm> 
        <tp>bug</tp> 
        <ablt>swarm</ablt>
        <wkns>fire</wkns>
        <img>beedrill</img>
    </Pkmn> 

</Data>
```

Pokemon.java:

```
package com.example.pokemon;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
//import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
public class Pokemon implements Serializable{

    @Element
    private String name;
    @Element
    private String type;
    @Element
    private String abilities;
    @Element
    private String weakness;
    @Element
    private String image;

    public Pokemon(){}
    public Pokemon(String n, String t, String a, String w, String i){
        name = n;
        type = t;
        abilities = a;
        weakness = w;
        image = i;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Data.java:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="Data", strict=false)
public class Data {
    @Element 
    private Pokemon pokemon;

    public Pokemon getPokemon() {
        return pokemon;           
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

[image: Stack_trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of things worth pointing out here:

Firstly, you've annotated the `pokemon` field in the `Data` class, but this is not going to work unless you supply the name of the xml tag the field should be bound up to. SimpleXML won't know that you actually mean the bind up `Pkmn` to `pokemon`. In short, add:

```
@Element(name="Pkmn") private Pokemon pokemon;
```

Last time I checked, SimpleXML does support auto-binding, but that will require the [`@Default` annotation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Default.html) and the field names have to match the xml tags.

That being said, the safest option here is to not use `@Default` and explicitly supply the name with every annotation. That is, go through your `Pokemon` class and declare the name for every `@Element` annotation. For example:

```
...
@Element(name="ablt") private String abilities;
...
```

After that, you should be close to have working code. To clean up, you may want to remove `strict=false` from the `@Root` declaration of your `Data` class. That was probably your initial attempt to bypass the `ValueRequiredException`? If the `Data` tag not having a `Pkmn` tag is a valid scenario, then potentially leave it in there, but otherwise you should remove it to avoid undesired side effects.